# Animation in Remote Views with ViewFlipper in app widget

Tags: android, android-widget, android-animation, viewflipper

I am trying to implement animation in my homescreen widgets. I checked out the activity code for the same but couldn't do the fling gesture or animation for the widget. Please Please guide. How should i link my remote Views and ViewFlipper object. Please reply.

Comment: Somebody please reply.. I ma struggling to find any example..

Comment: Why no one is replying, despite of the number of views? Is my question wrong or vague?